# Pass digits of a numeric string to an array in bash

Tags: bash

I have a number, say

```
number=5684398
```

and I want to store its digits into the fields of an array `coolarray` as follows:

```
coolarray[0]=5
coolarray[1]=6
coolarray[2]=8
coolarray[3]=4
coolarray[4]=3
coolarray[5]=9
coolarray[6]=8
```

How can I proceed?

Comment: `str_split` to do this

Comment: @Kisaragi, did you notice the "bash" tag?

Comment: Wasn't there before, so no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fold -w1` to break input string into each character:

```
number=5684398
coolarray=( $(fold -w1 <<< "$number") )

printf "%s\n" "${coolarray[@]}"
5
6
8
4
3
9
8
```

Comment: I know, but i was still in the 5 minutes lock after opening a question :)

Answer (score 5):

What I would do in pure [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) and [parameter expansions](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe):

```
number=5684398
len=${#number}
for ((i=0; i<len; i++)); do arr[$i]=${number:$i:1}; done
```

Comment: Or even better: `arr=(); while [[ $number ]]; do arr+=( "${number::1}" ); number=${number:1}; done`.

Answer (score 0):

Using shell arithmetic:

```
$ for (( i=${#number}-1; i>=0; i-- )); do ary+=( $((number / 10**i % 10)) ); done
$ printf "%s\n" "${ary[@]}"
5
6
8
4
3
9
8
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this simple one-liner:

```
number=5684398
unset coolarray; while read -n1 a; do coolarray+=($a); done <<< $number

echo ${coolarray[@]}
5 6 8 4 3 9 8
```

Explanation:  Bash build-in "read" can take one character at a time by using "n1". Array append structure +=() is used to buid the result. That "unset coolarray" is needed to avoid stacking up resulting array to previous array after each run time.